# Can this be optimized with less js code?

Tags: jquery

Currently have 3 dialogs for 3 different links.. Can this be written in less code?

js

```
$("a.link1").click(function(event){
    var msg = confirm('link 1, or cancel');

    if(msg){
        // go to destination
        return true;
    }else{
        // cancel
        return false;
    }
});

$("a.link2").click(function(event){
    var msg = confirm('link 2, or cancel');

    if(msg){
        // go to destination
        return true;
    }else{
        // cancel
        return false;
    }
});

$("a.link3").click(function(event){
    var msg = confirm('link 3, or cancel');

    if(msg){
        // go to destination
        return true;
    }else{
        // cancel
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Would this question be better of asked on [**codereview.stackexchange.com**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same class on all links, put your message in a data-attribute on each link and then

```
$('a.link').click(function() { 
  return confirm($(this).data('message'));
}
```

Html:

```
<a href="wherever.com" data-message="Are you sure?">Go to wherever</a>
```

Comment: Interesting idea.. do I put "a href=.. data-message="to change your password click ok" ?

Comment: You can also code `return confirm($(this).data('message'))`. No need to use `document.location` object.

Comment: @undefined that's right, brain fart on my part there... unless he wants to do something special return confirm... will do

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you both.  3 lines is much better than what I originally had.

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute selector with wild card to bind event and use some pattern for making link message of confirm.

```
$("a[class^=link]").click(function(event){
    var msg = confirm('link 1, or cancel');

    if(msg){
        // go to destination
        return true;
    }else{
        // cancel
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you do not have links with pattern you can use some array to store links

```
arr = {"link1", "link2", "link3"};
$("a[class^=link]").click(function(event){
    classIndex = this.className.replace('link', '')  

    var msg = confirm(arr[classIndex-1]+ ', or cancel');

    if(msg){
        // go to destination
        return true;
    }else{
        // cancel
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: he needs different messages for `confirm` for each link being clicked.

Comment: What if the links are class="user", class="password", class="register"
Yes, thanks varnie..

Comment: @Josh: If you expect common functionality you would give them all the same class. Off course you can still give them any other class but the one class should be assigned to all which lets you target them for their common use. You also could use a common `data-attribute` and target them that way instead. `$("a[data-group=link]")`. Lots of options :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[class^=link]').click(function() {

    if ( confirm($(this).attr('class') + ', or cancel') ) {   
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Or do you need the space between the text "link" and the number?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do something like this:

```
$("a.confirmlink").click(function(){
   return confirm("Go to " + $(this).attr("href") + "?");
});
```

Comment: `href` is an attribute native to the [**anchor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a) element. `this.href` works, no need to wrap it into a jquery object.